# ¿Para que sirve agregar /faces/ en el web.xml?

Tags: java, jsf

Necesito aclara esta duda. Espero me ayuden.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<display-name>jsfdemo</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

¿Ese url-pattern (/faces/*) es obligatorio que aparezca en todas las URL de mi aplicación? Veo que algunos ejemplo al desplegar sus demos si se les muestra inmediatamente una URL así.

[image: prueba1]

Pero a mí me sale así:

[image: prueba3]

Y si le agrego el /faces/ me muestra el componente JSF:

[image: prueba2]

Digamos que todo se ve como cualquier duda de novato y algo pude haber hecho mal. Pero luego veo proyectos así:

[image: pfavanzado1]

[image: pfavanzado2]

Que en ninguna parte de la aplicación usa el /faces/ en su URL. La verdad ya busqué algo claro pero aun no logro entender de si va o no va.

Plus: Acabo de encontrar uno dónde ni pone el /faces/ en el web.xml. Ya no sé que pensar. Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esa parte del web.xml que comentás estas declarando como es el patrón de url que el servlet **"Faces Servlet"** va a saber interpretar.

Primero, ¿Que es un servelt?

Bien, un servlet no es mas que una clase java que sabe escuchar pedidos HTTP, como por ejemplo un GET o un POST. Antes de que existieran frameworks como Struts, Spring o JSF, los desarrolladores Java creaban aplicaciones web dinámicas usando servlet, que se desplegaban en algún servlet container (como Tomcat, por ejemplo). Como esto era bastante engorroso o había que hacer mucho trabajo, nacieron los frameworks web, que hacen muchísimo trabajo por nosotros y los cuales están construidos sobre esta tecnología de Servlets. (De hecho, si te fijas en tu web.xml estas declarando un servlet de JSF)

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Para contestar tu pregunta, vos podes poner lo que quieras como url-pattern, lo que declarás ahí es que tipo de url´s va a estar escuchando el servlet que esta configurado.

Comment: Ya lo entendí. Justo después de publicar me llegó una epifanía. En realidad le día la lectura número 100 a uno de mis materiales de estudio. Ahora con tu respuesta me confirmas que si lo entendí claramente. Gracias por colaborar.